# Magento 2 CLI command stops working after adding constructor

Tags: php, magento, command-line-interface, magento2

I have made an CLI command in magento 2 to process CSV file, but when I'm adding `__constructor()` to use `ProductRepository` to manage my products via CSV my terminal starts to showing following error:

```
There are no commands defined in the "xxx" namespace.
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Command\Console\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\OutputTest;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Class importProducts
 */
class importProducts extends Command
{
    const FILE_NAME = 'file_name';
    const COLS = 'cols';
    
    protected $pr;

    public function __construct(ProductRepository $pr, string $name = null)
    {
        $this->pr = $pr;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('xxx:isp');
        $this->setDescription('Imports products.');
        $this->addOption(
            self::FILE_NAME,
            'f',
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'File name'
        );
        $this->addOption(
            self::COLS,
            'c',
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'Number of columns'
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $fileName = $input->getOption('file_name');
        if (!isset($fileName)) {
            $output->writeln('Please provide file name!');
            return 0;
        }

        $file = file('pub/command/import2.csv');
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $file);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: without __constructor everyting works just fine but I have no idea how to manage my products without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't come up with any other solution, here's a fast "hack" to make it work:

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Command\Console\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\OutputTest;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;


/**
 * Class importProducts
 */
class importProducts extends Command
{
    const FILE_NAME = 'file_name';
    const COLS = 'cols';
    
    protected $pr;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('xxx:isp');
        $this->setDescription('Imports products.');
        $this->addOption(
            self::FILE_NAME,
            'f',
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'File name'
        );
        $this->addOption(
            self::COLS,
            'c',
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'Number of columns'
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // this is not the recommended way to do this!
        $this->pr = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ProductRepository::class);
        $fileName = $input->getOption('file_name');
        if (!isset($fileName)) {
            $output->writeln('Please provide file name!');
            return 0;
        }
        $file = file('pub/command/import2.csv');
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $file);
        return 1;
    }
}
```